# Custom Validation and Messgae for jquery-validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

We're using jquery-validate to do validation on an existing web application.  Our application is dynamically updating min and max attributes on form fields.  There are some cases where the min and max may be equal.

If min and max are equal, I want to display "Please enter {value}", otherwise, if max, "Please enter a number less than or equal to {max}."

Any ideas?

Comment: How about showing us the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Otherwise, I think you'll need to write a custom function that incorporates `min` and `max` into one method so you can do the dynamic messaging.

Comment: Can you use the `range` attribute instead of separate `min` and `max` attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `range` method rather than `min` and `max`. Then you can use a custom message function that checks whether the start and end of the range are the same:

```
messages: {
    "fieldname": {
        range: function([min, max], element) {
            if (min == max) {
                return `Please enter ${min}`;
            } else {
                return `Please enter a number between ${min} and ${max}`;
            }
        }
    }
}
```